# Dart 2.17.0: how do I enable "enhanced-enums"?

Tags: dart, enums

Code example:

```
enum ShareType {
NONE('N'),
PUBLISH('P'),
  SHARE('S');

final String key;
const ShareType(String keyToSet) {this.key = keyToSet;}
}
```

gives error:

> This requires the 'enhanced-enums' language feature to be enabled.

How do I enable this feature?
Where must this be set?

Comment: Also, your constructor is invalid for a `const` constructor. Use `const ShareTyp(this.key);` or `const ShareType(String keyToSet) : key = keyToSet;` instead. A const constructor cannot have a body, and a final field cannot be initialized in a constructor body anyway, only in the initializer list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go into your `pubspec.yaml` file in your project and make sure that the minimum version for the `sdk` are `2.17.0` like:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"
```

The reason for this is that Dart keeps track of when features are introduced and makes sure your project does not make use of features that would not be compatible for the range of versions your project have specified as required.

Comment: Thx. I'm already on Dart 2.17.0 but still had version >= 2.16 in pubspec.yaml.